# Multiple workflows in a sharepoint feature

Tags: 2007, workflow, solution-package

Really simple - I'm wondering if it's possible to pack multiple custom workflows in a single wsp-solution/feature.

I thought I could just create the workflows, and then add multiple instances of  elements in the elements.xml, but only one of the workflows is selectable in sharepoint (the first alphabetic I believe)

Is there any way? I would hate to have to create a feature for each workflow :/

**Update**

To be more specific, what I have is a WSPBuilder w/ workflows project, in which I have a feature, with feature.xml and elements.xml.

Then I have a "WorkflowCode" folder - as supplied by WSP Builder, with 4 different workflows.

In my elements.xml it automatically created a workflow element for my first workflow, looking like:

```
<Workflow
       Name="CRU Application Class"
       Description="Workflow for creating/editing Application Class"
       Id="7266DAF0-B438-4850-A995-23A8544DB208"
       CodeBesideClass="Elsymboler_workflows.CreateAppClass_WF"
       CodeBesideAssembly="Elsymboler_workflows, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bb4eedb04c635c01"
       TaskListContentTypeId="0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160"
   AssociationUrl="_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx"
       InstantiationUrl="_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx"
       ModificationUrl="_layouts/ModWrkflIP.aspx"
       StatusUrl="_layouts/WrkStat.aspx">

    <Categories/>
    <!-- Tags to specify InfoPath forms for the workflow; delete tags for forms that you do not have -->
    <MetaData>
        <!--     <Association_FormURN>associationFormURN</Association_FormURN>
  <Instantiation_FormURN>instantiationFormURN</Instantiation_FormURN>
  <Task0_FormURN>taskFormURN</Task0_FormURN>

  <Modification_GUID_FormURN>modificationURN</Modification_GUID_FormURN>
  <Modification_GUID_Name>Name of Modification</Modification_GUID_Name>
  -->
        <AssociateOnActivation>false</AssociateOnActivation>
    </MetaData>
</Workflow>
```

I don't know enough about the parameters and such to tell what is needed and what isn't, but I expected to be able to simply copy/paste this element, and merely changing the name, codebesideclass and add a fresh GUID for the ID, in order to add the rest of my workflows - but this doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just add more workflows and pack them into a single feature. The OOB UI in Visual Studio 2010 should facilitate this nicely.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should've clarified - I'm working in MOSS 2007

Comment: Well, it's working now - even though I didn't do anything else. I guess maybe the GAC just hadn't gotten properly updated or something :)

Answer (score 1):

You can place any number of elements inside one feature, expect some limitations. But this is a bad way of packaging. For workflows you might need a separate **packages**. it's greatly simplifies upgrading and development.

For *deplotyment* you can use Activation Dependencies.

Comment: Why is packaging workflows together "bad"?

Comment: If you have multiple coded workflows in one assebmly changing assembly version will break all workflows.

Comment: Definitely good to know. You could just update the DLL and not update the version number.

Comment: Does this happen with any other code besides workflows? We are about to start using Assembly Versions in solutions with a lot of features/custom class libraries inside them. Would that break too?

Comment: Any compiled code affected by assembly versioning. But lot of elements binded with code in sharepoint can be simply reprovisoned, expect workflows and webparts. A BindingRedirect solves this issue for webparts. Running coded worflows will fail on changing assemby version, and no builtin mechanism to avoid this.